# How to iterate active directory groups (roles) in MS Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, active-directory

I have some code which will return true if a user is in a specific group that I pass in, however if the user is in another group that is part of the goroup I'm passing in, the function will return false. I need to be able to iterate through the groups to see if the user may be a member of a group that is in the group I'm interested in.

So as an example, if a user is in GroupA and all members of Group_A are in Group_B and I need to know if the user is in Group_B, which they are by being in Group_A.
Here is what I have now:
****EDIT added function GetCurrentUser used in IsUserInRole()

```
Public Function GetCurrentUser() As String
    GetCurrentUser = Environ("USERNAME")
End Function

Public Function IsUserInRole(role) As Boolean
Dim UserObj As Object
Dim GroupObj As Object

Dim strObjectString As String
strObjectString = "WinNT://my domain/" & GetCurrentUser() & ""
Set UserObj = GetObject(strObjectString)

For Each GroupObj In UserObj.Groups

Debug.Print GroupObj.Name

   If GroupObj.Name = role Then
        IsUserInRole = True
        Exit Function
   End If
Next
```

End Function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I got a solution to this through MS. I have some code on the Access Form that passes a Group  name into a function that lives in a Module. The function iterates through all the Groups the user is a member of and itereates through any Groups within the Group passed in. It returns true if the user is a member of the Group or is a member of a Group that is a member of the passed in Group.

Code on Form:

```
strGroup = "_System Admin"
If IsCurrentUserInGroup(strGroup) = True Then
    MsgBox "In System Admin"
End If
```

Declared Public variables at top of Module:

```
Public strOut As String
Public objGroupList, objUser
```

IsCurrentUserInGroup Code:

```
Function IsCurrentUserInGroup(ByVal strGroup) As Boolean

Dim objSysInfo As Object
Dim strDN As String

'Get currentlly logged in users info
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
strDN = objSysInfo.UserName

On Error Resume Next
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strDN)
If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
   On Error GoTo 0
   MsgBox "User not found" & vbCrLf & strDN

End If
On Error GoTo 0

' Bind to dictionary object.
Set objGroupList = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

' Enumerate group memberships.
If EnumGroups(objUser, "", strGroup) = True Then
    IsCurrentUserInGroup = True
Else
    IsCurrentUserInGroup = False
End If

End Function
```

EnumGroups Code:

```
Public Function EnumGroups(ByVal objADObject, ByVal strOffset, ByVal strGroup) As Boolean
' Recursive subroutine to enumerate user group memberships.
' Includes nested group memberships.
Dim colstrGroups, objGroup, j
objGroupList.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
colstrGroups = objADObject.memberOf
If (IsEmpty(colstrGroups) = True) Then
    Exit Function
End If
If (TypeName(colstrGroups) = "String") Then
    ' Escape any forward slash characters, "/", with the backslash
    ' escape character. All other characters that should be escaped are.
    colstrGroups = Replace(colstrGroups, "/", "\/")
    Set objGroup = GetObject("LDAP://" & colstrGroups)
    If (objGroupList.Exists(objGroup.sAMAccountName) = False) Then
        objGroupList.Add objGroup.sAMAccountName, True
         strOut = strOut + strOffset & objGroup.distinguishedName + Chr(13) + Chr(10)
        Call EnumGroups(objGroup, strOffset & "--", "")
    Else
        strOut = strOut + strOffset + strOffset & objGroup.distinguishedName & " (Duplicate)" + Chr(13) + Chr(10)
    End If
    Exit Function
End If
For j = 0 To UBound(colstrGroups)
    ' Escape any forward slash characters, "/", with the backslash
    ' escape character. All other characters that should be escaped are.
    colstrGroups(j) = Replace(colstrGroups(j), "/", "\/")
    Set objGroup = GetObject("LDAP://" & colstrGroups(j))
    If (objGroupList.Exists(objGroup.sAMAccountName) = False) Then
        If objGroup.sAMAccountName = strGroup Then
            EnumGroups = True                 
        End If
        objGroupList.Add objGroup.sAMAccountName, True
        strOut = strOut + strOffset & objGroup.distinguishedName + Chr(13) + Chr(10)
        Call EnumGroups(objGroup, strOffset & "--", "")
    Else
        strOut = strOut + strOffset & objGroup.distinguishedName & " (Duplicate)" + Chr(13) + Chr(10)
    End If
Next
End Function
```

Comment: Hi there! I am currently using this code in one of my projects, but I have to make a small change.  There are no nested groups to be checked for my project, how can I change the function to not require to check nested groups and improve performance?

Comment: @Childishforlife, I added the GetCurrentUser() function to my original post. You should be able to use it to pass a group name in and have True returned if the user is in the group. Make sure you preplace the "my domain" with your domain name. Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry I am a tad bit confused. I was wondering if there was anyway to change EnumGroups to not be recursive, and to not check groups inside groups and only check "top level" groups, as the system I am working in does not require checking nested groups.